# how could I copy files from and to external sdcard in Android 4.4+?

Tags: android

In my application user need to be able to copy the db files to use in inventory task but seems I'm not able to copy files from and to storage/extSdcard in Android 4.4+

If I use

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to get the External path it works but copies the file to the storage/0 where user doesn't have access via windows explorer

and if I try to use

```
sd = new File("storage/extSdCard/anyexternalfolder
```

then it does not work.

I've added the permission

`android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

to AndroidManifest.xml but it does not work in Android 4.4+

But, not long ago, I've installed Spotify and BeyondPod and they created folders in the external sdcard.

How did they do this?

It would great if someone could point me the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"How did they do this?"_ Using `getExternalFilesDirs` or `getExternalMediaDirs` perhaps?

Comment: Sorry Michael, I think you didn't get it right. I'm not having trouble getting the right folder. The problem is that I don't have permission to write there or I don´t know how to get this permission.

Comment: Thanks Lakhan for editing this to a more friendly layout.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can get write permission to anywhere on the external SD card. The two methods I mentioned should give you paths to directories that you can write to.

Comment: That's right. It seems I don't have permission after Android 4.4+ But how Spotify got this permission?

Comment: By using either of those methods that I mentioned?

Comment: I tried this

[code]
         File sd =  getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
[/code]

But this export my database to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/Download where
user can not see through Windows Explorer. I would like to export to /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.my.package/files/Download